# PHP Mail not sending when hosted on Plesk

Tags: email, email-headers

My first post and I really need some guidance, I have spent weeks researching and trying to understand why my mail code does not appear to be working on the corporate hosting(Plesk) vs. my personal hosting(CPanel) - (both on GoDaddy)

I have a number of areas within my site that I send emails, either to a newly registered user or when a user has downloaded software. The newly registered email I send works on both CPanel and Plesk

My problem is on the hosting of my personal website (CPanel), the following code works fine. However, when using the exact same code on my corporate hosting (Plesk) this does not work. I am pulling my hair out and would really appreciate a steer from you experts.

This is the code:

```
$to = "myname@myemail.com";
$subject = "Trial Software downloaded";
$headers.= 'From: "Test Mail" <noreply@myemail.com>';
$headers.= 'Reply-To: "Reply Mail" <noreply@myemail.com>';
$headers.= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers.= 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$Message = 'Software Downloaded' . "\n\n" . 'The following registered user 
has just downloaded a trial' . "\n\n" . 'Name: ' . $Fname . " " . $Lname . 
"\n" . 'Company: '. $Company . "\n" . 'Email: '. $Email . "\n" . "Product: " 
. $Product . "\n" . 'Date: ' . $a . "\n\n" . "An evaluation license for " . 
$Product . " requires sending to " . $Email;
mail($to, $subject, $Message, $headers);
```